# Mixed content problem onepage checkout ssl

Tags: onepage-checkout, ssl, https

i have a big problem on Onepage Checkout on Magento 1.7.0.2.
I can not find the place where getAdditonal get the data.

```
Load mixed active content "http://xxx.de/de/checkout/onepage/getAdditional/" was blocked.
```

Where can I insert the secure part:

```
array('_forced_secure' => true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use shell to access your environment you can easily try to use the grep commando to search where the url is used:

```
grep -r 'getAdditional' app/design/frontend/*
```

This will then result in

```
getAdditionalUrl()
```

Which is declared in

app/code/core/Mage/GiftMessage/Block/Message/Inline.php

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

`shipping.onSave = function(evt){
    new Ajax.Updater('onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load', '<?php $_urlHttp = $this->getAdditionalUrl(); $_addNew = str_replace("http://", "https://", $_urlHttp); echo $_addNew; ?>', {onSuccess: function() {
          this.nextStep(evt);
    }.bind(this), evalScripts:true});
}.bindAsEventListener(shipping);`

`billing.onSave = function(evt){
    new Ajax.Updater('onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load', '<?php $_urlHttp = $this->getAdditionalUrl(); $_addNew = str_replace("http://", "https://", $_urlHttp); echo $_addNew; ?>', {onSuccess: function() {
          this.nextStep(evt);
    }.bind(this), evalScripts:true});
}.bindAsEventListener(billing);`

str_replace:

`<?php $_urlHttp = $this->getAdditionalUrl(); $_addNew = str_replace("http://", "https://", $_urlHttp);`